# Visual Studio VSIX Installer issue-- could not load file or assembly

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio Professional 2022 installed.  I am trying to install several extensions from the Marketplace, but the installer is failing to run.  For example, after I download the Microsoft Analysis Services Projects 2022 (Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices) extension and try to open that vsix file, the VSIX Installer raises the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=17.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.  The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have tried repairing my install of Visual Studio, but that didn't resolve the issue.  I have also uninstalled all other instances of Visual Studio from my machine.

How can I resolve this issue?